# org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): db.UserMapper.xxx

Tags: java, xml, orm, mybatis, dropwizard

Facing exception while running a DROPWIZARD application

ERROR [2016-12-30 04:36:34,735] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 6813de3aa499e307
! org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): db.UserMapper.

```
@Path("/user/{username}")
 public class ExampleResource {

 private final SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public ExampleResource(SqlSessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @GET
    public User getUser(@PathParam("username") String username) {

        try (SqlSession session = sessionFactory.openSession()) 
        {
           UserMapper users = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
            //session.getConfiguration().addMapper(UserMapper.class);
            //UserMapper users = session.getMapper(UserMapper.class);
            return users.findByUsername(username);
        }

    }
}
```

UserMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="db.UserMapper" class="db.UserMapper">
<select id="findByUsername" resultType="User">
<![CDATA[
    select username,email
    from user
    where username = #{username}
]]>
</select>

<resultMap id="User" type="core.User">
    <id column="username" property="username" />
    <result column="email" property="email" />
</resultMap>

<insert id="addUser">
<![CDATA[
    insert into user (username, email)
    values (#{User.username}, #{User.email})
]]>
</insert>
```

```
user mapper.java

public interface UserMapper {

 User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

    void addUser(@Param("user") User user);
}
```

ConfigurationClass:

```
@Valid
@NotNull    

private DataSourceFactory datasourceFactory = new DataSourceFactory();

@JsonProperty("database")
public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
        return this.datasourceFactory;
    }
public void setDatabase(DataSourceFactory database) {
    this.datasourceFactory = database;
}
```

Comment: Where you have kept the xml file? Are you using maven? also post configure file, to understand have you are adding mapp*xml files

Comment: xml file in the project were we keep .yml file.I m using this Mapper.xml file only to map the interface, no other configuration file.

Comment: Not sure how you do it in dropwizard, but say you have directory mapper where you kept all mapper.xml, for SqlSessionFactoryBean in you need to set factory.setMapperLocations("classpath:/mapper"); In your configuration nowhere you are saying where is mapper.xml located(to be searched for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we are using mybatis with dropwizard in main class we initialize
mybatisbundle, at that time provide the package name where your mapper class is located.
**Hightlighted in code below.**

```
private final MybatisBundle<TestDropWizardConfiguration> mybatisBundle = new MybatisBundle<TestDropWizardConfiguration>("**com.example.helloworld**") {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(TestDropWizardConfiguration configuration) {
        return configuration.getDataSourceFactory();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

my problem is spring don't find mapper.xml,but take @Test can find .
my XXXmapper.xml and XXXXmapper.java in the same position (src/main/java/..../).
i move  all XXXmapper.xml to ”src/main/resources/mapper“,and add `<property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:mapper/*.xml" />` in `<bean id="sqlSessionFactory>`.
Then is ok!

maybe you could search "how many methods configure the XXXmapper.xml about mybatis" from Google .
hope to help you :-)